# getQuantityString() method not working

Tags: android

this is my strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <plurals name="subtitle_plural">
        <item quantity="one">%1$d crime</item>
        <item quantity="other">%1$d crimes</item>
    </plurals>
</resources>
```

and this is my code using plural:

```
CrimeLab crimeLab = CrimeLab.get(getActivity());
int crimeSize = crimeLab.getCrimes().size();
String subTitle = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.subtitle_plural, crimeSize, crimeSize);
```

when crimeSize is 1, variable `subTitle` should be `1 crime`, but it always be `1 crimes`。

anyone help me, why `getQuantityString()` not working at here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change you plurals into below

```
 <plurals name="subtitle_plural">
    <item quantity="one">%d crime </item>
    <item quantity="other">%d crimes </item>
</plurals>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. And the reason is language environment (Chinese) is not supported.